# Looking for a better way to authenticate Google Cloud Function with a service account. Right now I'm storing the credentials json file on the backend

Tags: authentication, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-oauth

I'm looking for a better way to authenticate Google Cloud Function with a service account. Right now I'm storing the credentials json file on the backend. This is the code for my app https://github.com/ChristianOConnor/spheron-react-api-stack. This app could be deployed on any hosting platform, but at the moment the app is built to deploy on a Web3 protocol called Spheron. TLDR, Spheron runs the backend express server on a web3 friendly content serving/hosting platform called Akash. This means that whoever is hosting my backend express server has access to my GCP service account's credentials. You can see all of the code in the link I provided but just for ease of access this is the server.js file which will be on Akash.

server.js

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
require("dotenv").config();
const GoogleAuth = require("google-auth-library").GoogleAuth;
const cors = require("cors");

app.use(
  cors({ origin: process.env.ORIGIN, credentials: process.env.CREDENTIALS })
);

app.get("/hello", async function (req, res) {
  const keyInJsn = JSON.parse(process.env.CREDENTIALS_STR);
  const auth = new GoogleAuth({
    credentials: keyInJsn,
  });
  const url = process.env.RUN_APP_URL;

  //Create your client with an Identity token.
  const client = await auth.getIdTokenClient(url);
  const result = await client.request({ url });
  const resData = result.data;
  res.send(resData);
});

var server = app.listen(8081, function () {
  var host = server.address().address;
  var port = server.address().port;
  console.log("Example app listening at http://localhost:", port);
});
```

`process.env.CREDENTIALS_STR` is the service account credentials set up in this format:

```
CREDENTIALS_STR={"type": "service_account","project_id": "<PROJECT ID>","private_key_id": "<PRIVATE KEY ID>","private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\<PRIVATE KEY>\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n","client_email": "<SERVICE ACCOUNT NAME>@<PROJECT NAME>.iam.gserviceaccount.com","client_id": "<CLIENT ID>","auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth","token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token","auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs","client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/<SERVICE ACCOUNT NAME>.iam.gserviceaccount.com"}
```

The Akash provider can see this string. Is there a better way to do authentication for a GCP service account that doesn't expose the credntials to a hosting/server provider?

Also don't be throw off by the web3 stuff. This app essentially works the same as a traditional web2 app with a backend and a client. If it helps you to think about it different, picture that I'm deploying on Netlify with a static client and a Netlify Function.

Comment: I've never worked with java or js, and never worked in your context, but, as a general design consideration - did you think about using Secret Manager https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager for storing credentials? The cloud function (code) can fetched the credentials in run time, for example, so there is no need for keeping them neither in configuration nor in environment variables.

Comment: Do you have an identity with your web3 service? Something based on OAuth2?

Comment: @al-dann Doesn't secret-manager require a service account to authenticate? And even if I set it to no authentication, I think the server would still receive a plain text version of the secret key. If I set the function to reach out to the secret manager directly, I would still need to call the function without authenticating. It's like a weird Catch-22 lol.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Identity for a web3 service? That sound promising, do you know of a relevant example?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere oh I found this article you wrote https://medium.com/google-cloud/secure-cloud-run-cloud-functions-and-app-engine-with-api-key-73c57bededd1. Is this a way to do it? Should I make a cloud run endpoint to run the function?

Comment: You can now use API Gateway, a managed service by Google Cloud based on ESPv2 (and my article is still valid but with API Gateway APIs)

Comment: For sure some service account is used to run a cloud function (to execute the code of the cloud function). And that service account can be granted all required permissions (including relevant SM secrets access) using ordinray IAM capabilities. In addition, that service accoutn has nothing to do with the identity and credentials of the caller of this cloud function. What the 'service down the line' is going to get - is entirely a design decision implemented inside the code of the cloud function. But if that further service requires some secrets - the SM may be a good candidate for storing it.

Comment: @al-dann is this an example of what you're talking about, and would this work for what I'm doing https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/iam-credentials/latest ? Also, if this would work, where do I put the token? As a `Bearer: token` header in a get request to the function trigger url?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere are you saying that I should replace "endpoint-id" with "API Gateway?"

Comment: I mean, the whole ESPv2 product is now managed by API Gateway. You no longer need to deploy it on Cloud Run, it's managed. You only have to configure it.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere is this the best guide on how to use it https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/set-up-cloud-run-espv2. Or is there a better guide that you're familiar with?

Comment: Prefer that: https://medium.com/google-cloud/how-to-use-google-api-gateway-with-cloud-run-60698959b342

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere This tutorial also uses "API Gateway" is that outdated in favor of "ESPv2?"

Comment: The opposite, prefer a managed solution than ESPv2

Comment: Okay gotcha thanks, I will keep trying to get this to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compromise I came to was creating an API Gateway for the function. This allows the function to be called without any credentials and still run from a service account. It creates a separate quasi-vulnerability though, as anyone with the API Gateway link can also call the function unauthenticated.

First, I enabled Service Management APIs, API Gateway API, and Service Control API. Then I made an API Gateway with my service account that runs my referenced cloud function. I uploaded a file like this for the api spec:

```
swagger: '2.0'
info:
  title: api-gateway-cloud-function
  description: API Gateway Calling Cloud Function
  version: 1.0.0
schemes:
  - https
produces:
  - application/json
paths:
  /whateveryouwanttocallthispath:
    get:
      summary: My Cloud Function
      operationId: whatever
      x-google-backend:
        address: <CLOUD_RUN_URL>
      responses:
        '200':
          description: OK
```

You can test it by running the function via curl command in a bash terminal `curl {gatewayId}-{hash}.{region_code}.gateway.dev/v1/whateveryouwanttocallthispath`. It works with no credential json file.

The problem is that you could achieve a similar result by just allowing the function to be called unauthenticated... Idk if this method has many benefits.